# using async await in a handle submit

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I've only been studying react for 6 months so maybe a newbie question.... but I have a handle submit which is working on a login form, although i want to direct a user (role:user) to one page and if admin (role:admin) to a different page so wrote the below code checking the role of the user (this is a test project so security is not particularly important. The issue I'm having (why its not working) is because the `currentUser` code runs before the fetch... is there a way to use async await or another way to wait for the fetch before running this code ?

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/login`, {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((userData) => {
      setCurrentUser(userData.user);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error('FETCH ERROR:', error));

  currentUser.role === 'admin' ? history.push('/admin') : history.push('/');
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answers

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers you need to have your redirect executed inside a `.then`. The point you are missing is that when you are chaining `.then` methods, only what you return from the previous `then` will  be available to the next so what you should do is:

```
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((userData) => {
    setCurrentUser(userData.user);
    // if you don't return this you won't have access to it in the next .then
    return userData.user;
  })
  .then((currentUser) => {
    // so now it won't be undefined since you are returning from previous .then
    console.log("currentuser from login", currentUser);
    return currentUser;
  })
  .then((currentUser) => {
    currentUser.role === "admin"
      ? history.push("/admin")
      : history.push("/");
  })
```

Also you can do all this inside a single `.then` method

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation - that makes sense and works ! Hope you have a good day  ✌️ 

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
    currentUser.role === "admin" ? history.push("/admin") : history.push("/");
```

inside of the `.then` block. The `.then` block executes after the promise is resolved.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering @daniel-duong... yes that did make sense although i've tried that in the below code and it not working, i've added a console log to see the current user within the fetch and it comes back as undefined.... i have no idea why, if you have any other recommendations please let me know - thanks

````
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/login`, {
      credentials: "include",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((userData) => {
        setCurrentUser(userData.user);
      })
      .then(() => {
        currentUser.role === "admin"
          ? history.push("/admin")
          : history.push("/");
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("currentuser from login", currentUser);
      })
      .catch((error) =>
        console.error("Fetch error from login handlesubmit...", error)
      );```
````